# List authorized resources in UMA 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, api-authorization

I'm looking at UMA 2.0 for fine grainde authorization in my webapp. But UMA 2.0 requires a client to try accessing a resource hosted on a Resource Server, get back an HTTP 401 error and a ticket to use when asking the Authorization Service for an authorization token.

But this prereqs that the client knows which resources it wants to access or which resources do exist on the Resource Server.

In my scenario I have something similar to a set of repositories on GitHub and a user can be authorized to one or more of them. When the user logs in I would like to show him the repositories he has access to.

Is there any standard way to query the Resource Server/Authorization Server for the list of resources the user is entitled to access?
How does UMA 2.0 assumes a client will discover existing resources it is authorized to access?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking into this. According to the documentation I found you can list resources at the Resource Registration Endpoint (/resource_set):

> Create a GET request to the UMA resource_set endpoint, including the
> PAT bearer token in an Authorization header.

Request:

```
curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer 515d6551-6512-5279-98b6-c0ef3f03a723" \
--header "Accept-API-Version: resource=1.0" \ 
https://openam.example.com:8443/openam/uma/realms/root/resource_set
```

Response  (a list of ids):

```
{
    "126615ba-b7fd-4660-b281-bae81aa45f7c0",
    "3a2fe6d5-67c8-4a5a-83fb-09734f1dd5b10",
    "8ed24623-fcb5-46b8-9a64-18ee1b9b7d5d0"
}
```

Some links about this topic:

- https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7/uma-guide/managing-uma-resource-sets.html#to-list-uma-resource-sets
- https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_protection_resources_api
- https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-federated-authz-2.0.html#list-rreg
- https://docs.gravitee.io/am/current/am_devguide_protocols_uma2_overview.html#resource_registration_endpoint